# What would I use to let me use the GPIO pins on my RPi without soldering directly onto the pins & without a breadboard?

Tags: gpio, breadboard, pi-b+

Is there a 'thing' that I can use to use the GPIO pins on my B+ *without* soldering and *without* a breadboard?

I know I could use a breakout board with a ribbon cable and breadboard, but that adds an extra ribbon cable and breadboard. Does something exist which is like a breadboard I can just plonk on top of the GPIO pins *without soldering* onto the GPIO pins?

The reason I want this is because I want to be able to reuse my pi for other GPIO projects, but at the same time, I don't want to add unnecessary weight to my robot!

It doesn't need to be something that is permanent - just something that would work for a few months.

I hope you understand what I mean - if not, please ask me for more information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There's this](http://www.adafruit.com/products/2310?gclid=CjwKEAjwtMqrBRDwtoehx72vm34SJACl_Un1lWI4oMx9ZJt2QaaKB5gHKXIMbnPLkAOr8z6bg8qeixoCV3Xw_wcB), but it's pretty hard to beat a regular breadboard for prototyping. If you don't want to use all the pins or a ribbon cable you could just get a [bunch of these to make individual connections with no soldering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A6SOGC4). You can also first make your circuit up on a breadboard, and when you get it how you want it make a permanent board, which would be light and compact.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Grove connectors.  No breadboard.  Just plugs you can not plug in backwards.   Here is a tutorial on using Grove connectors:

http://www.switchdoc.com/2016/02/tutorial-intro-to-grove-connectors-for-arduinoraspberry-pi-projects/